# Save PDF in black and white with given DPI using Python

Tags: python, pdf, reportlab, pdfrw

I have a Python program doing some manipulation on PDF file names.

My colleague has asked if I can:

1. Open each PDF and save with the new file name, and
2. Change the PDF to black and white (remove any colour), and
3. Save with a fixed DPI of 300.

I'm vaguely aware of [reportlab](http://www.reportlab.com/opensource/) and [pdfrw](https://github.com/pmaupin/pdfrw) but don't know if they, or other libraries, can do these operations.

Any example code would be much appreciated.

Comment: Be aware that a PDF document does not inherently have a "DPI".  That's because a PDF page is not a bitmap. It may _contain_ bitmaps, but many PDF files contain only text and vector graphics that can be rendered at any resolution.  If you want to render each PDF document to a sequence of 300 dpi bitmaps, there are libraries that can do that.  (Off-topic to ask for libraries on StackOverflow though.)  And if you want to change bitmaps to monochrome or bi-level, there are libraries that can do that too.  But note! some documents could get _bigger_ as a result.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know how to read a PDF then save it again in black and white?